# Laravel how to return css in function

Tags: php, css, laravel, bootstrap-4, sass

So I have a function which I want to return this span class code

I already set the class code in my CSS

```
.subject{
   position:absolute;
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 0px 25px 12px 0px;
   display: inline-block;
   border-radius: 2px;
}
```

So my function created is this

```
function subject() {
return '<span class="subject"></span>';
}
```

I call the function like this in the blade

```
{{subject()}}
```

May I know why when I call the function it just return the code

```
'<span class="subject"></span>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After receiving on the blade, function contains HTML tag. Then you must use a single curly brace in each side and double exclamation marks on both side of the function call, and this is the most common ways of laravel not escaping  HTML in the blade template:

```
{!!subject()!!}
```

Comment: Wow ur a life saver thank you so much. May I know where can I read about this {!! !!}. I don't know what isit called and how does it works

Comment: Just read documentation

Comment: Found it https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#other-blade-control-structures thankss